# primeface migration problem with ajax events from 6.2 to 7.0

Tags: ajax, jsf, primefaces, xhtml

hello please i need help ; i have a working simulation in my web page that has some buttons with bean methods that works fine and updates some components in the page using p:componenet_id and works fine too in 6.2 until i upgraded to primeface 7.0
now all it does is refreshing the form when i click on the same buttons
and skips any bean method called ;

**MAIN PROBLEM :** is that now ajax is refreshing my page whenever i try using commandlink or radio button which both use either ajax tag or update and process that targets other components by their ID along with calling some backing beans methods!

Comment: p:component is still there, its removed in 8.0: https://primefaces.github.io/primefaces/11_0_0/#/../migrationguide/8_0

Comment: okay great so at least i can for now still use p:component syntax 
but my problem still persist which is everytime a command is clicked the form is refreshed , all the form and also it reexecute the java code in the backing beans used there while skipping the main action of the button clicked ! :(

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: @MD.RAKIBHASAN done ; thx for the suggestion ; i hope i find a solution for this blocking problem

Answer (score 0):

**UPDATE** : so i found out that the p:componenet('ID_comp') is still supported in primefaces 7.0 but will be removed in 8.0
so now that i am still at 7.0 i am sure that  p:componenet('ID_comp') is not the one making the non expected behavior ;
but i am using the primefaces extension jar version 7.0.2 and primefaces jar 7.0 and the project seems to work fine except for this page

also another thing i noticed is that when i write ajax="false" on  that commandlink , it does nothing at all ; nothing is executed in bean or interface ; and of course ajax="true " make again that same unexpected behaviour.

and the main problem now that although my code in xhtml is still the same ; the ajax is the one that is making a non expected behaviour which makes the actionListener does not execute at all .
here is a code example of what does not working and the current senario  :

```
  <p:commandLink value="Search" process="@this" actionListener="#{bean.newPerson(true)}" rendered="#{empty bean.offre.id and !disabled}"
                                       update=":#{p:component('panelPerson')} :#{p:component('toolbar_person')}" type="button"   >
                            <p:resetInput target="panelPerson" />
                        </p:commandLink>
```

so what this should do is to open an input for searching a person and empty all inputs in a form ,also execute the function bean.newPerson(true) which is not the case that is hapeneing ;
**here in version 7.0 although i never changed that code** ; all it does now is to refresh the hole form ,with skipping bean.newPerson(true) and with executing a bean methode that initialize the page(which only should be executed at the opeing of the page') also it resets all the inputs.
is it something related to ajax or maybe the action,Listener is no longer functional ??or what's exactly cuasing the change between 6.2 and 7.0 while it  is the same code .

**N.B** : this also happens with almost every button in the form that have an actionlistener on it (commandlinks and radio button ) ;always re execute the bean.init and reset all the form as if i reloaded the hole page .

Comment: hi again ; 2 weeks later and the problem still persist in 7.0 i can't fix it .